# Azure Media Services V3 : Encoded Audio File not able to play in Azure Media Player

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-media-player

My Video file encoding and playing has been working well, but encoded Audio only files are not able to play in Azure Media Player.
In Media player, it shows the initial loading circle, but never starts playing the audio.

Below is the Transform creation code;

```html
TransformOutput[] outputs = new TransformOutput[]
{
   new TransformOutput
(
     new StandardEncoderPreset
     (
        codecs: new Codec[]
        {
           new AacAudio
           (
             channels: 2,
             samplingRate: 48000,
             bitrate: 128000,
             profile: AacAudioProfile.AacLc
           ),
 
     new H264Video
     (                                  
        keyFrameInterval:TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        layers:  new H264Layer[]
        {
           new H264Layer
          (
             bitrate: 600000,
             width: "640",
             height: "360",
             label: "SD"
          )
        }
     ),
 }

new TransformOutput(analyzerPreset)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/randomnumber/2017/06/21/azure-media-player-support-for-audio-only-and-video-only-streams/ and http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/features.html, audio only streams are not supported by Azure Media Player.  To play audio only you'll need to use a different player.

Comment: Well, Audio only files which I had encoded couple of months back are still playing well in same Azure Media Player even today! Only those audio files which I am encoding today are not able to play. And, I can see the difference in size of the same encoded file in these 2 months. Also, link you shared are from 2017, so not sure if this is still not supported today in 2019.

Comment: What I found is, the Audio plays as it is supposed to in AMP, only when it is encoded with "EncoderNamedPreset.AdaptiveStreaming". Not e.g. with "StandardEncoderPreset". Looks like a bug to me.